# need to fix the problem in my javascript code

Tags: javascript

I wrote a code for calculating the mode in javascript but its giving me an error. Can anyone suggest me where I am making mistake?

```
numbers = [6,4,77,66,6,69]
currentwinner = 1
winningfrequency = 0
counterindex = 0
contender = 1
contendercount = 0
while (counterindex< numbers.length){
  contender = numbers[counterindex]
  contender = 0
  countingindex = 0
  while (countingindex<numbers.length){
    if (numbers[counterindex]==contender){
      contendercount = 0
    }
    countingindex +=1
    if (contendercount>winningfrequency){
      contender = currentwinner
      winningfrequency = contendercount
    }
    contenderindex +=1
  }
  mode = currentwinner
  document.write(mode)
```

Comment: Syntactical errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Frost said in the comments, there are many syntactical errors, including:

- Missing semicolons on most lines. Acceptable if you are new and come from a language like python.
- Your first while loop is missing the closing brace.

There are also some logic errors:

- Have you learned a `for` loop? It is better for this purpose.